# Google Drive API - Manipulate comment's html content

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to add/modify html content to [Google Drive's comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource). By the comment's definition page linked, it looks like `htmlContent` is not writable.

Using the *Try this API* button [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/update) I've successfully created, updated and listed comments.

In fact, if I use [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/update), I am able to send some `htmlContent` to the comment. Although it does not work as intended, and it just shows my html code.

```html
<span style="color:blue;">Hello</span>
```

So, is it actually possible to add some html to Google Drive's comments?

If not, why is there an `htmlContent` in the object at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation for [htmlContent](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource)

[image]

It appears to not be write able.

> So, is it actually possible to add some html to Google Drive's comments?

Though the api it appears this is not possible.

> If not, why is there an htmlContent in the object at all?

This may be left over from the v2 of the api, only google could answer this question really.